# jsPDF creates PDF with colour different than original

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, png, jspdf

I am creating PDF from *base64* encoded PNG image. Resulting PDF has noticeably different colour hue that original PNG image.

Same *base64* encoded image is rendering correctly in browser.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', false);
doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 100, 200, 280, 210, undefined, 'slow');
doc.save( type + '.pdf')
```

Comment: So did you report an error on the project's github?

Comment: I have created issue on project's github https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/577

Comment: can u put your code, maybe there can be a coding bug

Answer (score 0):

PNG images may have gamma information in them. Some browsers read that information and "fix" the colors when displaying the image.

When the image is parsed by jsPDF, it processes the gamma information differently then your browser. jsPDF is either applying gamma correction and your browser isn't, or vice versa.

For a consistent result, you could try removing the gamma information form your original PNG using a tool like TweakPNG for Windows or PNGCrush and ImageOptim for Mac.

Comment: I've used PNGCrush to explicitly remove gamma information from original PNG image and I got exactly the same result I was getting when using jsPDF to save the PDF. This confirms that jsPDF is ignoring or not handling correctly the gamma information.